# How can I overcome this error Error in tbl_vars(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

I am trying to perform an inner join on 2 tables.

One is a hotel dataset which I have tokenized before using

```
df1 = read.csv("chennai.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

hotel <- df1 %>% unnest_tokens(word,Review_Text)
data("stop_words")
hotel <- hotel %>%
   anti_join(stop_words)
head(hotel)

      Hotel_name                          Review_Title Sentiment
 1 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3
 2 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3
 3 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3
 4 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3
 5 Accord Metropolitan Excellent comfortableness during stay         3
 6 Accord Metropolitan                   Not too comfortable         1
   Rating_Percentage  X X.1 X.2 X.3     word
 1               100 NA      NA  NA     nice
 2               100 NA      NA  NA     stay
 3               100 NA      NA  NA business
 4               100 NA      NA  NA  tourist
 5               100 NA      NA  NA  purpose
 6                20 NA      NA  NA    hotel
```

I have also used a simplified version of General Inquirer Dictionary spreadsheet

```
 df <- read.csv("ib.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 dat <-subset(df, select=c(2,1))
 head(dat)

        word  Scoree
 1           A        
 2     ABANDON Negativ
 3 ABANDONMENT Negativ
 4       ABATE Negativ
 5   ABATEMENT        
 6    ABDICATE Negativ
```

I have tried to do an inner_join where I encounter this error.

```
 observation<- hotel %>%
 +     inner_join(dat, by = "word") %>% 
 +     count(Scoree)
```

Comment: Right off the bat, `hotel$word` has lowercase words, and `dat$word` has uppercase.  But please provide a reproducible example if you'd like help.

Comment: The hotel data set("chennai.csv") I used is available at the following link https://www.kaggle.com/ranjitha1/hotel-reviews-city-chennai/data

Comment: THe other one("ib.csv") http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/inquirerbasic.xls

Comment: I created a new column with the following excel command =IF(J3="Hostile", "Hostile",IF(E3="Positiv","Positiv",IF(K3="Strong","Strong",IF(F3="Negativ","Negativ",""))))